# is window.external synchronous or not

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I have just discovered the `window.external` object that allows to call C# function in a winform program hosting a IE-like browser.

I red the doc on MSDN and some threads on stackOverflow but I didn't found if those calls are synchronous or not, and, is it customable ?

The only thing I have founded in the MSDN doc doesn't speak about this subject =/

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: I made some tests. It's seems that the calls are asynchronous. I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These calls are naturally synchronous, but often it makes sense to process them asynchronously, to avoid otherwise possible reentrancy into JavaScript code. You could use [SynchronizationContext.Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) for that.

E.g. you call `window.external.TestMethod()` from JavaScript. On the .NET side it may look like this:

```
this.webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new ObjectForScripting(this.webBrowser);

// ...

[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ObjectForScripting
{
    WebBrowser _browser;
    SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public ObjectForScripting(WebBrowser browser)
    {
        _browser = browser;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        _context.Post(_ =>
        {
            _browser.Document.InvokeScript("alert", new object[] { 
                "Process a call from JavaScript asynchronosuly." });
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: A different way but nevertheless with this same concept is to pass a JS function that would be called asynchronously. I have yet to check if this is possible though.

Comment: Actually, this seems possible, again thanks to @Noseratio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21150022/314056