# Mocking a javascript callback in a c# host application

Tags: c#, javascript, unit-testing, webbrowser-control

I am creating a c# application that has an embedded webbrowser control. From javascript I am calling a c# method and passing a javascript callback. I am using the dynamic technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150022):

```
public void CallbackTest(object callback)
{
    dynamic callbackFunc = callback;
    callbackFunc("Hello!");
}
```

My problem is how would I go about unit testing this method?  How do I mock (or fake) the callback parameter? For what it's worth, my mocking library of choice is Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that you could just pass in an `Action<String>` and this should work as a callback. I am not sure if you can get support for this kind of dynamic in `Moq` directly, though. But, using an `Action` is pretty straightforward anyway

```
var mockCallBack = new Action<String>(str => {return;});
CallbackTest(mockCallBack)
```

Comment: That's it. Don't know why I had such trouble coming up with that on my own. :) Thanks.